# I don't understand these errors im getting with my on_member_join/on_member_remove functions

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I've been working on discord bot coded in python. And i've been trying to get my bot to say a message when a user joins the server and leaves the server. But when i tested it out, i got 2 errors which i don't understand the errors. And im not sure what i did wrong. If anybody could help explain these errors, and point me in the right direction for my code i would greatly appreciate it.

I have looked into the discord rewrite api and have tested it in my server with a friend which is when i got the errors

```
@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    channel = member.server.get_channel("499457708978864151")
    msg = 'Welcome to the {1.name} Server, {0.mention}'
    await client.say(channel, msg.format(member, member.server))

@client.event
async def on_member_remove(member):
    channel = member.server.get_channel("499457708978864151")
    msg = '{0.mention} has left the server'
    await client.say((channel, msg.format(member, member.server)))
```

I expected my bot to say Welcome to the (the name of the server) Server, @username when they entered the server, and @username has left the server when the user left but i received these errors:

```
TypeError: send_message() takes from 2 to 3 positional arguments but 4 were given
discord.errors.InvalidArgument: Destination must be Channel, PrivateChannel, User, or Object. Received NoneType
```

Here is my full traceback

```
Ignoring exception in on_member_join
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Chris\PycharmProjects\untitled1\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 307, in _run_event
    yield from getattr(self, event)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:/Users/Chris/PycharmProjects/untitled1/RomaniBot.py", line 37, in on_member_join
    await client.say(channel, msg.format(member, member.server))
  File "C:\Users\Chris\PycharmProjects\untitled1\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 350, in say
    coro = self.send_message(destination, *args, **kwargs)
TypeError: send_message() takes from 2 to 3 positional arguments but 4 were given
Ignoring exception in on_member_remove
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Chris\PycharmProjects\untitled1\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 307, in _run_event
    yield from getattr(self, event)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:/Users/Chris/PycharmProjects/untitled1/RomaniBot.py", line 43, in on_member_remove
    await client.say((channel, msg.format(member, member.server)))
  File "C:\Users\Chris\PycharmProjects\untitled1\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 309, in _augmented_msg
    msg = yield from coro
  File "C:\Users\Chris\PycharmProjects\untitled1\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 1145, in send_message
    channel_id, guild_id = yield from self._resolve_destination(destination)
  File "C:\Users\Chris\PycharmProjects\untitled1\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 289, in _resolve_destination
    raise InvalidArgument(fmt.format(destination))
discord.errors.InvalidArgument: Destination must be Channel, PrivateChannel, User, or Object. Received NoneType
```

Comment: Can you post the full traceback?

Comment: @pkqxdd i edited the question with the full traceback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One easy fix for your code would be to, instead of using `client.say`, to use `channel.send`. So

```
@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    channel = member.server.get_channel(499457708978864151)
    msg = 'Welcome to the {1.name} Server, {0.mention}'
    await channel.send(msg.format(member, member.server))
```

In addition, according to the documentation,

> get_channel(id)
>
> Returns a abc.GuildChannel or abc.PrivateChannel with
>   the following ID.
>
> If not found, returns None.

So you did not select the channel successfully. The reason is that the ID in rewrite is an `int`, not a string.

Comment: @ChristopherCollar If you think this answer helped you, please consider to accept and/or to upvote the answer.

Answer (score 0):

`member.server` returns you the server, where the member joined. And you tried accessing the channel with the ID `499457708978864151`, this would definetly not working in other servers than the server where the channel is with the ID `499457708978864151`, so you have to get the server too `client.get_server("ID")` would do this.

Comment: I'm sorry, it's `guild`, not `server` and IDs are Integers, so it would be `client.get_guild(ID)`

Comment: so it would be channel = client.get_guild("ID")?

Comment: No, it would be `guild = client.get_guild(ID)` and then `channel = guild.get_channel(ID)`.